# how to create three edit fileds in horizontal field manager in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

How to create three editfields like this [image]

```
 HorizontalFieldManager hfm_city=new HorizontalFieldManager();
 VerticalFieldManager vfm_city = new VerticalFieldManager();
 vfm_city.setBorder(
                  BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(
                  new XYEdges(12,12,12,12), borderBitmap
                          )
                  ); 
            vfm_city.setMargin(0, 200, 0, 0);
            final EditField city = new EditField("", "", 30, BasicEditField.FILTER_DEFAULT){
                                            String emptyString = "City";
                                            protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
                                                g.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF);
                                                g.clear();
                                            }
                                            protected void paint(Graphics g) {
                                                int oldColor = g.getColor();
                                                try {
                                                    g.setColor(0x000000);
                                                    test = super.getText();
                                                    if ( test == null || test.length() < 1 ) {
                                                        //g.setColor(Config.hint_colour);
                                                        g.drawText(emptyString, 0, 0);
                                                    }
                                                    super.paint(g);
                                                } finally {
                                                    g.setColor(oldColor);
                                                }
                                            }
                                          };
                                          vfm_city.add(city);




                                      VerticalFieldManager vfm_state = new VerticalFieldManager();
                                      vfm_state.setBorder(
                                              BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(
                                                  new XYEdges(12,12,12,12), borderBitmap
                                              )
                                          ); 
                                      vfm_state.setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
                                          final EditField state = new EditField("", "", 30, BasicEditField.FILTER_DEFAULT){
                                            String emptyString = "State";
                                            protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
                                                g.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF);
                                                g.clear();
                                            }
                                            protected void paint(Graphics g) {
                                                int oldColor = g.getColor();
                                                try {
                                                    g.setColor(0x000000);
                                                    test = super.getText();
                                                    if ( test == null || test.length() < 1 ) {
                                                        //g.setColor(Config.hint_colour);
                                                        g.drawText(emptyString, 0, 0);
                                                    }
                                                    super.paint(g);
                                                } finally {
                                                    g.setColor(oldColor);
                                                }
                                            }
                                          };
                                          vfm_state.add(state);


                                          VerticalFieldManager vfm_zip = new VerticalFieldManager();
                                          vfm_zip.setBorder(
                                                  BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(
                                                      new XYEdges(12,12,12,12), borderBitmap
                                                  )
                                              ); 
                                          vfm_zip.setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
                                              final EditField zip = new EditField("", "", 30, BasicEditField.FILTER_DEFAULT){
                                                String emptyString = "Zip";
                                                protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
                                                    g.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF);
                                                    g.clear();
                                                }
                                                protected void paint(Graphics g) {
                                                    int oldColor = g.getColor();
                                                    try {
                                                        g.setColor(0x000000);
                                                        test = super.getText();
                                                        if ( test == null || test.length() < 1 ) {
                                                            //g.setColor(Config.hint_colour);
                                                            g.drawText(emptyString, 0, 0);
                                                        }
                                                        super.paint(g);
                                                    } finally {
                                                        g.setColor(oldColor);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                              };
                                              vfm_zip.add(zip);



                                      hfm_city.add(vfm_city);
                                      hfm_city.add(vfm_state);
                                      hfm_city.add(vfm_zip);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going in the right way. but you have to give specific width & height to your`VerticalFieldManager` otherwise it will take full width by default.

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm_city = new VerticalFieldManager() {
    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        super.sublayout(Display.getwidth()/3,30);
        setExtent(Display.getwidth()/3,30);
    }
};
```

Do this in your State & city `vfm` and add in your `hfm` and try.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer

```
{

        Border bdr = BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(4, 4, 4, 4),Border.STYLE_SOLID);


        VerticalFieldManager vert=new VerticalFieldManager()
        {
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
            }

        };
            HorizontalFieldManager hr=new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT)
            {
                protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                    super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),50);
                    setExtent(Display.getWidth(),50);
                }
            };
            hr.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GREEN));
            EditField e1=new EditField(Field.FOCUSABLE|Field.FIELD_VCENTER){

                protected void layout(int width, int height) {
                    super.layout(100,30);
                    setExtent(100,30);
                }
            };
            EditField e2=new EditField(Field.FOCUSABLE|Field.FIELD_VCENTER){

                protected void layout(int width, int height) {
                    super.layout(60,30);
                    setExtent(60,30);
                }
            };
            EditField e3=new EditField(Field.FOCUSABLE|Field.FIELD_VCENTER){

                protected void layout(int width, int height) {
                    super.layout(60,30);
                    setExtent(60,30);
                }
            };
            e1.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE));
            e2.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE));
            e3.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE));
            e1.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
            e2.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 20);
            e3.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
            e1.setBorder(bdr);
            e2.setBorder(bdr);
            e3.setBorder(bdr);
            hr.add(e1);

            hr.add(e2);

            hr.add(e3);


            vert.add(hr);
            add(vert);


    }
```

[image]